# How to change face lip color change using MLKit in android?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, google-mlkit

I wanted to change lips color of face using MLkit like below pictures

Original Images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvJcb.png)

after changes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaoPD.png)

below code is what I do.
But it didn't work

Below code getting taking lip Contour

```
 FaceDetectorOptions options = new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_ALL)
                .build();
        FaceDetector detector = FaceDetection.getClient(options);

        Bitmap faceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face4);

        InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(faceBitmap, 0);
        Task<List<Face>> result = detector.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(faces -> {
                    for (Face face : faces) {
                        FaceLandmark upperLipLandmark = face.getLandmark(UPPER_LIP_TOP);
                        if (upperLipLandmark == null)
                            upperLipLandmark = face.getLandmark(UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM);
                        FaceLandmark lowerLipLandmark = face.getLandmark(LOWER_LIP_BOTTOM);

                        if (upperLipLandmark != null && lowerLipLandmark != null) {
                            RectF lipRegion = getLipRegion(upperLipLandmark.getPosition(), lowerLipLandmark.getPosition());

                            Bitmap modifiedLipBitmap = changeLipColor(lipRegion, faceBitmap, Color.GREEN);

                            Bitmap resultBitmap = combineModifiedLips(faceBitmap, modifiedLipBitmap, lipRegion);

                            imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
                            ivLip.setImageBitmap(modifiedLipBitmap);
                            ivLip2.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
                        }

                      
                    }

                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    // Handle error
                    e.printStackTrace();
});
```

Here change lip color and draw lip bitmap

```
private RectF getLipRegion(PointF upperLipPosition, PointF lowerLipPosition) {
        float left = Math.min(upperLipPosition.x, lowerLipPosition.x);
        float top = Math.min(upperLipPosition.y, lowerLipPosition.y);
        float right = Math.max(upperLipPosition.x, lowerLipPosition.x);
        float bottom = Math.max(upperLipPosition.y, lowerLipPosition.y);
        return new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```